# Common ancestor/interface between EventHandler and KeyEventHandler?

Tags: c#, inheritance, eventhandler

Is there a common ancestor or interface shared by EventHandler and KeyEventHandler? I've looked at the documentation and maybe I'm just missing it, but they seem completely disjoint.

Assuming there is no such common link between them, what is the best way to store a collection of many EventHandlers *and* KeyEventHandlers?

Comment: Delegates do not support any way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both KeyEventHandler and EventHandler are delegates. This code works:

```
public void DelegateTest()
{
    var delList = new List<Delegate>();
    delList.Add(new KeyEventHandler(SomeFunction));
    delList.Add(new EventHandler(SomeFunction));
    foreach (var element in delList)
        element.DynamicInvoke(null, null);
}

public void SomeFunction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Got called!");
}
```

Calling `DelegateTest()` will write "Got called!" twice on the output.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I'm currently doing, I just wanted to be sure there wasn't a more appropriate way.